# How do I use XPath to capture a portion of a p tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, discourse

I've seen plenty of similar questions on here but still can't get my particular use case working.
XPath newby here.

I have the following snippet of ruby code

```
        post_html = Nokogiri::HTML(post.raw)
        @restricted_file_types = SiteSetting.file_attachment_whispers_file_extensions.split('|')
        Rails.logger.info "searching for restricted extensions #{@restricted_file_types.inspect}"
        Rails.logger.info "post is: #{post_html}"


        # trying to get links
        tags = post_html.xpath("//p[contains(., '\[.*')]")
        Rails.logger.info "tag from regex: #{tags}"

        tags.each do |attachment| 
            Rails.logger.info "p tag found in parsing"
            Rails.logger.info "#{attachment}"
            does_contain = @restricted_file_types.any? {
                |extension| attachment.include?(extension)
            }

            Rails.logger.info 'checking for restricted'
            if contains_restricted?(attachment)
                Rails.logger.info 'contains restricted'
                links.push(attachment)
                node = post_html.create_element 'p'# create paragraph element
                node.inner_html = SiteSetting.file_attachment_whispers_message
                attachment.replace '[color=red]' + node + '[/color]' # replace found link with paragraph
                post.raw = post_html
                post.save!
                hasUpdated = true
            end
        end
```

post.raw will contain something of a similar structure to this example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>this is a dog that borks. Image of dog attached.

[3408.zip|attachment](upload://szj2cSHQnbp8zsuBeC7ZsZ9mllg.zip) (19.7 KB)</p></body></html>
```

My goal is to replace the link to a file with a message. To do that i was trying to capture just that portion of the html to change it all and then rewrite it. I'm getting stuck on how to properly use xpath in this situation. post_html.xpath("//p[contains(., '[.*')]") does not work.

I don't fully understand what the first parameter in xpath does since I got that from another example. Nor do I understand how this comes back with nothing matched. Can someone explain what exactly that is doing and why it is not working?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you also provide the resultant html you are expecting? Is this the only html format you will always get?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like :

```
concat(substring-before(//p,"["),"I love dogs")
```

First, for each p element we extract everything before the "[" with substring-before function. Then we "paste" the message we want with concat.

Output :

```
this is a dog that borks. Image of dog attached. I love dogs
```